# Unable to use Tor Settings in Ubuntu

Tags: firefox, proxy, tor

I use a proxy to connect to internet, and it requires authentication too. I have downloaded the extracted tor bundle for linux. Vidalia starts and i can browse successfully within the Firefox already bundled with the tor.
But when I use Socks5 proxy 127.0.0.1 and port 9050 in my normal firefox browser, I get the error: "Server not found."

Here is a screenshot of my current proxy settings:

[image]

and this is what i get:

[image]

I have been doing the same in windows, it works. Please help here.

Comment: Is this when you are using tor or not using tor?

Comment: i started the tor from the tor bundle, and its working in the portable firefox over there. but this is my native firefox settings. Earlier i had the settings of my host proxy that i use to connect to internet. I changed this to work using tor. But it does not work.

Comment: @Jobin changing to these settings gives me error

Comment: Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your native firefox has to use your proxy settings to work correctly. So depending upon your proxy settings, set the host and port no accordingly in **Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Network -> Settings**

The firefox that comes bundled with tor is capable to work bypassing the proxy, so use the settings for bypassing proxy with the one that comes bundled with tor.

Comment: then what about the thing mentioned here : http://www.torproject.org.in/docs/tor-doc-web.html.en can't i use its settings in any other application?

Comment: Seems like the answer I posted is inaccurate, can you confirm if the firefox bundled with tor is able to connect to the internet?

Comment: tor works fine in the bundled browser, and i am not able to use tor proxy with my home browser (that comes preinstalled with ubuntu)